# Poupulate Dropwdown from values in a column - AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a dropdown menu and I am using AMPscript to populate my dropdown from the ItemName column in my Data Extension. I am not certain how to get all values in the ItemName column so that I can bind them to my dropdown. This is still relatively new to me. So if you need more info please let me know

Here is my start. And I know my @curList is missing something, just not sure what.

```
SET @curList = LookupOrderedRowsCS(@listDe,0, @ItemName)

Row Count: %%=ROWCOUNT(@curList) =%%
```

(I know I can set i to Row Count and loop through to bind the records to the dropdown.)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.  You can modify the output to build your select options.

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName",@numRowsToReturn,"DEColumn1 desc, DEColumn2 asc","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"DEColumn1")
set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"DEColumn2")

]%%

Row %%=v(@i)=%%, DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%, DEColumn2 is %%=v(@DEColumn2)=%%

%%[

next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```